# How can i juin two model in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Event_Data_His_Dtl, TViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x, y => 
                       y.MapFrom(p => eventSetting.Where(s => 
                       s.EventCode == p.EventCode).Select(s => s.EventDesc).FirstOrDefault()));
        });
```

My eventSetting is Model as value

Key to Value

but TViewModel generic I can't Know How to work